# Vim Spell option to ignore source code identifiers containint underscore, numbers, etc

Tags: vim

Is there any option in vim spell checker to ignore words containing underscore, multiple uppercase letters, minus, numbers in a plain text file. I could not find anything in the manuals (7.2) or Google search.

Comment: I want to find an option that makes it ignore identifiers in my source that are found within string literals or comments... right now it marks them as spelling errors, even though the comment is often about the very thing it says is misspelled.

Comment: `:help spell-syntax`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `syntax` command with the `@NoSpell` cluster:

```
syn match myExCapitalWords +\<\w*[_0-9A-Z-]\w*\>+ contains=@NoSpell
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look at `:help iskeyword` variable which defines what 'word' is.

Comment: Vim doesn't use `'iskeyword'` for spell checking.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `zg` when on the bad word - this will add the word to the allowed word list, which should then stop it being highlight in the future.

Otherwise, I'm not sure whether this is possible using the standard functionality - syntax files can specify regions that should or should not be spell checked but this will not help you, as you are including 'bad words' in comments, which would be spell checked in most cases.