# vim spell check: ignore capitalized words?

Tags: vim

How can I tell Vim's spell checker to ignore words which have a leading capital?

It's annoying that, for example, `MyWidget` is flagged as a spelling error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim Spell option to ignore source code identifiers containint underscore, numbers, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773865/vim-spell-option-to-ignore-source-code-identifiers-containint-underscore-number)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a syntax element to ignore spell checking.

```
" Ignore CamelCase words when spell checking
fun! IgnoreCamelCaseSpell()
  syn match CamelCase /\<[A-Z][a-z]\+[A-Z].\{-}\>/ contains=@NoSpell transparent
  syn cluster Spell add=CamelCase
endfun
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * :call IgnoreCamelCaseSpell()
```

Note that the `autocmd` is necessary to make sure that the syntax rules are loaded *after* the syntax definitions for the file type have been loaded (as the syntax rules wipe out any existing syntax rules).

However I'll personally prefer to add them (with `zg`) as good, so I can check there is no typo rather than ignoring everything.

Comment: Ah, of course. I didn't think of this. I've updated your answer with the complete function necessary to correctly ignore CamelCase words, even if an existing syntax is loaded.

Comment: And, yes — you're right that simply upper case is a bit aggressive… Which is why I've switched to only ignoring CamelCase words.

Comment: ok, I put the uppercase as an example. Your function is obviously better (with the transparent and stuff, I'm not on an expert on syntax setting)

Comment: The better would be obviously to tell the spell checker to split the camel case word and check bit individually. That seems possible with the COMPOUNDFLAG.

Comment: Ya… But as I've been playing with this, it makes me realize that I also want to ignore things like email addresses and URLs, so a more general than COMPOUNDFLAG is needed.

Comment: Doesn't work here either with vim 7.3; even when using `/Xy/` it'll still highlight `Xy` as a spelling mistake. And what is the `.\{-}` supposed to do?

Comment: \{-} means 0 or more, as few as possible

Comment: This solution does not work in Vim 8+. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch available for vim that adds this functionality
https://github.com/btucker-MPCData/vim/commit/8801705b7a4a64db39de65ea56e982132488ebde
[Showing the 'Spelng' part of the token is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkDUU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Was also recently searching for good solution on smart spell check for vim/nvim. The best seems to be the coc-spell-check(https://github.com/iamcco/coc-spell-checker) after comparing with other plugins.

It basically gives you same experience as vscode's spell check. The exception words list is typically stored under `~/.config/nvim/coc-settings.json`'s `cSpell.userWords` object.

Answer (score -1):

Just add MyWidget and all the other class names into your personal dictionary. Lookup vim help file to find out the personal dictionary name. Automate this away into a script.

Comment: Eehh… I guess I could write a script to dump my tags files into my personal dictionary… But it would sure be a whole lot easier if I could `set spell_ignore=^[A-Z]` or something.

Comment: An alternative, but more complex, way: `:help spell-mkspell` and `:help spell-COMPOUNDFLAG`. After reading those I think the "dump the tags" seems easier.