# How to force vim spellchecker to ignore lowercase/uppercase errors

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196399/exclude-capitalized-words-from-vim-spell-check) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561603/vim-spell-check-ignore-capitalized-words/7569127) how to force Vim spell checker to ignore words with capital letters from being check. But my case is quite opposite. I want to ignore words that in corrected form include capital letters.

So in sentence:

*europe was chozen best*

only word **chozen** is the wrong one.

How to achieve that?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was posted first by [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich) on [vi&vim stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16180/how-to-force-vim-spellchecker-to-ignore-lowercase-uppercase-errors):

> I don't think that Vim has a setting for this. One workaround is to
>   create a new spellfile that contains everything in your current spell
>   file(s) but with lowercase letters only:
>
> 1. Create a new buffer containing everything from the spell file(s) currently in use:
>
>    ```
>    :spelldump
>    ```
> 2. Delete lines that don't contain any upper-case characters. This isn't strictly necessary, but there's no point keeping duplicate
>      entries for lower-case words:
>
>    ```
>    :v/\u/d
>    ```
> 3. Convert the entire file to lower-case, ignoring lines that contain the locations of the spell files:
>
>    ```
>    :v/^#/norm gu$
>    ```
> 4. Save the file:
>
>    ```
>    :w ~/.vim/spell/lowercase.utf-8.add
>    ```
> 5. Start using this file in addition to the standard files in Vim's `$VIMRUNTIME` directory. Note that Vim uses a default `'spellfile'`
>      value internally if the setting is empty, so if you already have any
>      existing spell files, you will need to ensure that they are included
>      in this setting (which accepts a comma-delimited list):
>
>    ```
>    :set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/lowercase.utf-8.add
>    ```
>
>    Note that if you set this option in a running instance of Vim, it
>      doesn't seem to take effect for spell-checking until you interact with
>      it (by, e.g. using the `zg` command.)
>
> The above doesn't affect the way that Vim detects lower-case words at
>   the start of a sentence as spelled incorrectly. You can disable this
>   with the `'spellcapcheck'` option:
>
> ```
> :set spellcapcheck=
> ```